# Google map is not showing what could be the problem in my script?(closed)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

What could be the problem in my script why my google map is not showing?
I want to add some element click event to zoom or to jump on that location but after adding some changes my map is not showing up.

**Got it working Code updated.**

```
<script>
var map;
var markerArr = [];

function initMap() {

var myLatLng = {lat: -32.74, lng: 115.72};

var mapProp= {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 5,
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    console.log(locations[i]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][0]
    });
    markerArr.push(marker);
}
}

function jumpToMarker(cnt){
    map.panTo(markerArr[cnt].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(15);
}
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBsKtyjwdGFWNdUML_0lXGph-6PaRNGKJHhhs3d0hgh7vE&callback=initMap">
```

What could be the problem in my script why my google map is not showing?
I want to add some element click event to zoom or to jump on that location but after adding some changes my map is not showing up.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I think your codes must have the "location" array somewhere ? please post this part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Google map APK key

```
<*script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script*>
```

You may follow the steps in the link below to get an API

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY20-Q3-global-demandgen-displayonnetworkhouseads-cs-GMP_maps_contactsal_saf_v2&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_m-CRE_434785623056-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Brand%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Google%20Maps%20Javascript%20API-KWID_43700053663474735-aud-903284319780%3Akwd-341556983684-userloc_1010294&utm_term=KW_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi&&gclid=Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmJh9xjiYPCqoQZ0CoTm8rj7nJllctB3qEbtuIJkUQEGcMWL6aA9zk4aAkW0EALw_wcB](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY20-Q3-global-demandgen-displayonnetworkhouseads-cs-GMP_maps_contactsal_saf_v2&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_m-CRE_434785623056-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7E%20Brand%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Google%20Maps%20Javascript%20API-KWID_43700053663474735-aud-903284319780%3Akwd-341556983684-userloc_1010294&utm_term=KW_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bmaps%20%2Bjavascript%20%2Bapi&&gclid=Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmJh9xjiYPCqoQZ0CoTm8rj7nJllctB3qEbtuIJkUQEGcMWL6aA9zk4aAkW0EALw_wcB)

Comment: I already have api key. google map is not showing after I did some changes in my script.

Comment: He probably figured it out